# Converting a type to unboxed type

Tags: haskell, unboxing

I am having trouble converting a type to unboxed type using derivingUnbox. I have tried below code but its giving error "parse error on input '->'" on line  `[t | Color -> Word32 |]`

```
    type Color = (Word8,Word8,Word8)


    colorToWord32 :: Color -> Word32
    colorToWord32 (r,g,b) = 0 .|. 
                           (shift (fromIntegral r) 24) .|. 
                           (shift (fromIntegral g) 16) .|. 
                           (shift (fromIntegral b) 8)

    word32ToColor :: Word32 -> Color
    word32ToColor color = (r,g,b)
        where
            r = fromIntegral (shift (color .&. 0xFF000000) (-24))
            g = fromIntegral (shift (color .&. 0x00FF0000) (-16))
            b = fromIntegral (shift (color .&. 0x0000FF00) (-8))


    derivingUnbox "Color"
        [t | Color -> Word32 |]
        colorToWord32
        word32ToColor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's fix the quote syntax:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  MultiParamTypeClasses, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

derivingUnbox "Color"
    [t| Color -> Word32 |]
    [| colorToWord32 |]
    [| word32ToColor |]
```

Second, note that this is still not right, since there is already an `unbox` instance for `(Word8, Word8, Word8)`. We have to create a new `data` or `newtype` if we are to define a new `unbox` instance.

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Deriving
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits

data Color = Color !Word8 !Word8 !Word8

colorToWord32 :: Color -> Word32
colorToWord32 (Color r g b) = 0 .|. 
                       (shift (fromIntegral r) 24) .|. 
                       (shift (fromIntegral g) 16) .|. 
                       (shift (fromIntegral b) 8)

word32ToColor :: Word32 -> Color
word32ToColor color = Color r g b where
  r = fromIntegral (shift (color .&. 0xFF000000) (-24))
  g = fromIntegral (shift (color .&. 0x00FF0000) (-16))
  b = fromIntegral (shift (color .&. 0x0000FF00) (-8))
```

Here we rely on the pre-existing `unbox` instance for `Word32`. Alternatively, we could just use the `unbox` instance for `(Word8, Word8, Word8)`:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as UV
type Color = (Word8, Word8, Word8)
```

Now we can simply use `UV.Vector Color`.

Note that the default `unbox` instance for tuples uses multiple unboxed vectors for the fields instead of using one vector and packing all the fields together (as we've done earlier). It depends on lookup patterns which configuration is faster in practice.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I will test both configurations to decide which one is faster for my application.